# How to overwrite an array cell in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1,2,3],
    'Name': ['abc', 'jkl', 'qwe'],
    'Array': [[1,2,3], [10,11,12], [4,5,4]]
})

    ID  Name    Array
0   1   abc [1, 2, 3]
1   2   jkl [10, 11, 12]
2   3   qwe [4, 5, 4]
```

Now I wan't to overwrite the array where `df['Name']=='qwe'` to `[17,23,5]`.
The correct output would look like this:

```
    ID  Name    Array
0   1   abc [1, 2, 3]
1   2   jkl [10, 11, 12]
2   3   qwe [17, 23, 5]
```

My ideas:

```
df.loc[df['Name']=='qwe', 'Array'] = [17,23,5]
-> ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

df.loc[df['Name']=='qwe', 'Array'] = [[17,23,5]]
-> ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray

df.loc[df['Name']=='qwe', 'Array'] = np.array([17,23,5])
-> ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

df.loc[df['Name']=='qwe', 'Array'] = pd.DataFrame({'Array':[[17,23,5]]})
->  ID  Name    Array
0   1   abc [1, 2, 3]
1   2   jkl [10, 11, 12]
2   3   qwe NaN
```

Is there an easy way to solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output for `df.loc[df['Name']=='qwe', 'Array']`?

Comment: try using the index  of the sub dataframe and pass the index in your dataframe on the right hand side of the last attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `Series` with filtered index values by mask:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1,2,3],
    'Name': ['abc', 'qwe', 'qwe'],
    'Array': [[1,2,3], [10,11,12], [4,5,4]]
})

m = df['Name']=='qwe'
df.loc[m, 'Array'] =  pd.Series([[17,23,5]] * m.sum(), index=df.index[m])

print (df)
   ID Name        Array
0   1  abc    [1, 2, 3]
1   2  qwe  [17, 23, 5]
2   3  qwe  [17, 23, 5]
```

Comment: when I tried, this is works with 1 qwe, but if 2 it will error (I changed the Name on 2nd row into qwe), I think the problems is in [[17,23,5]]

Comment: ohh I just know that you can do that in array, thanks you, I learn something new